# What's the benefit of using bytes package over strings?

Tags: go

http://play.golang.org/p/CZTmhNepkM

Can somebody explain why we need bytes? For example on the go playgound, I am doing the same thing but strings package is easier than bytes to use. Why would someone need bytes package for HasSuffix features while we have strings package?

```
 strings.HasSuffix(word, "ed")
 bytes.HasSuffix(word_byte, []byte("ed"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhen before Go v1.0 there was no `rune` type. That's why some methods in the standard library that work with parts of strings or iterate over "characters" would take a byte slice (instead of a rune slice).

Since a lot of methods take a byte slice and to avoid constantly converting to string and back - some basic functions exist for both types.

Comment: Noteworthy is that a conversion from `string` to `[]byte` is always O(n) as it needs a full copy (strings are immutable while `[]byte` is mutable). As this is expensive it is only logical to offer functions for manipulating `[]byte` without converting to `string`.

Comment: To add to @nemo — often you'll want to do all your heavy lifting with `[]byte` and then use `string` right at the end to minimize copying.

Comment: One more question, since most of text processing get the raw data as string format, is it non-optimal to convert the raw data in string format into byte format and do the processing and convert it back to string for output? It should be okay right?

Answer (score 3):

One important answer is performance. When doing massive string processing such as [this bioinformatics task](http://saml.rilspace.org/moar-languagez-gc-content-in-python-d-fpc-c-and-c) (fastest Go code [here](https://gist.github.com/samuell/5591369)), the byte slice API is a must.

Answer (score 0):

Go 1.8 further improves the bytes packages by optimizing its usage for ASCII sets.

See [commit 9a8c695](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/9a8c69539cbd052e2c4b55496d72ec8407c0af52) by [Joe Tsai (`dsnet`)](https://github.com/dsnet)

### > `bytes`, `strings`: optimize for ASCII sets

In a large codebase within Google, there are thousands of uses of:

```
ContainsAny|IndexAny|LastIndexAny|Trim|TrimLeft|TrimRight
```

> An analysis of their usage shows that **over 97% of them only use character
>   sets consisting of only ASCII symbols**.

```
Uses of ContainsAny|IndexAny|LastIndexAny:
     6% are 1   character  (e.g., "\n" or " ")
    58% are 2-4 characters (e.g., "<>" or "\r\n\t ")
    24% are 5-9 characters (e.g., "()[]*^$")
    10% are 10+ characters (e.g., "+-=&|><!(){}[]^\"~*?:\\/ ")
```

> We optimize for ASCII sets, which are commonly used to search for "control" characters in some string. We don't optimize for the single character scenario since `IndexRune` or `IndexByte` could be used